# Passing Struct pointer to a function

Tags: c

Sorry i'am a newbie. keep having problem with my function prototype and call. I think my function call or prototype is incorrect. I just want to pass the value of box.item and box.bin to the Stackers. 
actually what i wanted to do here is two have two Stack, one is a Stacker and Truck.
Both using Stack, for the `void truck(){}` uses dynamic memory allocation. and `void stacker(){}` a fixed size of 5. i have draw a image on what i wanted to do:

[image]

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



    struct box
    {
        int item;
        int bin;
        int top;
    }*boxs,stacker[5];

     void stackers(struct box *);

    int i;
    int num,a;
    int topt = -1;
    int tops = -1;


     void truck();
     void display();
void display()
{
    for(i=0;i<=topt;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d",boxs[i].item);
        printf("\n%d",boxs[i].bin);
        printf("\nstacker%d",stacker[i].item);
        printf("\nstacker%d",stacker[i].bin);
    }
}
    void main()
    {

        int op;//option
        char ch;//choice 

        do{
            system("cls");
            printf("\n Stack:-");
            printf("\n\n 1.<Insert>");
            printf("\n 2.<Display>");
            printf("\n\n Option: ");

            scanf("%d", &op);fflush(stdin);

            switch(op)
                 {
                     case 1:truck();break;
                     case 2:display();break;
                     default:printf("\n Invalid Choice!!!");break;

                 } printf("\n\n\n Continue?(Y/N): ");

                 scanf("%c", &ch);    fflush(stdin);
            }while(ch=='y' || ch=='Y');
        return;
    }


    void truck()
    {
        struct box e;
        int temp;

        printf("Enter Number of Boxes to unload from the Truck: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        boxs= (struct box*)malloc(num*sizeof (struct box));
        temp=num;
        /*tempt->tops=copy-1;*/

        for(a=0; a<num;a++)
        {
        topt++;
        temp--;
        /*tempt[copy-a].tops--;*/
        printf("\n1. Enter Item ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &e.item);
        boxs[a].item=e.item;fflush(stdin);
        /*tempt[copy-a].item=e.item;*/


        printf("\n2. Enter Bin ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &e.bin);
        boxs[a].bin=e.bin;fflush(stdin);
        //tempt[copy-a].bin=e.bin;
       stackers(boxs); 
        }

    }



void stackers(struct box * pass)
{
    if(tops==4)
    {

    }
    else{
        tops++;
        stacker[tops].item=pass->item;
        stacker[tops].bin=pass->bin;
    }
}
```

Comment: First and fundamental you cannot call a function _stackers(&boxs); // call_  outside of a block (eg `{ ... }` ).  Use a main() function to start things off, i.e. `int main(void){ ... }`.  See more comments below.

Comment: @ryyker i have updated my code and also draw a image of what i actually want my code to do. but my code now still unable to give me the result i want.

Comment: Because the original question as I remember it _is answered_, (in several places) there will be _fewer eyes looking at this post_.  But, because the current question is so different than what you originally posted, you can post this as a new question.  Include the content of this one, which by the way you have done a much better job of asking.  The graphic is good and will enable people to ask more precise questions, leading to precise answers, quicker.  So, re-post this _new_ question under a new name.  Perhaps under a title of:  ***Passing data using a struct*** (or similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
void stackers(struct box boxs);
... 
stackers(&boxs); // call
```

to

```
void stackers(struct box *);
... 
stackers(boxs); // call
```

---

**Updated:** For your new updated code, there are still several issues:

1. You didn't include needed headers:

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   ```
2. Put function declarations before `main()`, not in it:

   ```
   void truck();
   void display();
   void main()
   {
   ```
3. You didn't define function `display()`.

Comment: I am still having error on
    'stackers(&boxs);'
on the "&"

Comment: @BryanAnderson What error?

Comment: error C2664: 'stackers' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'box **' to 'box *'

Comment: Did you ever put your function call _into a block somewhere?_  You cannot call a function (except `main()`) outside of a function, eg. you might consider creating a _int main(void){...}_ somewhere.  (see example below for how)

Comment: @ryyker Yes, OP does need put the function call in e.g. `main()`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao i have updated my code above. and also explain on what i wanted to do. but i still can't make it work..

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

Stack:

```
struct box mybox;
stackers(&mybox); // call by address on the stack
```

Heap:

```
struct box * mybox_pointer = calloc(sizeof(struct box), 1);
stackers(mybox_pointer); // call by pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

***Here is another way...***

***Note:***  the use of `typedef`.  This allows you to *create* an instance of your structure by using the typedef'd name - BOX...

Read inline comments for (hopefully useful) explanations...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct 
{
    int item;
    int bin;
    int top;
}BOX; //BOX is now a type, and can be used to create instances of your struct.

BOX stacker[5], *boxs;//create array of 5, and pointer to an instance of the struct.

void stackers(BOX *a);//prototype of your function

       //stackers(&boxs); // call (you cannot call a function outside of a block, {...})
int main(void)//must include a main function (for any C program)
{             //program starts when operating system calls this function
    boxs = &stacker[0]; //initialize pointer to BOX like this
    stackers(boxs); // call it here (note, no & needed)
    return 0;
}

void stackers(BOX *pass)
{
    if(pass[0].top==4)
    {

    }
    else{//not sure what you are doing here, changes simply reflect what needed to be done for a compile build
        pass[0].top++;
        stacker[pass[0].top].item=pass[0].item;
        stacker[pass[0].top].bin=pass[0].bin;
    }
}
```